# How to close submenu when click on another submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to do a function that when i click on a submenu it opens, but when i click on another i want to close the one previosly opened.

This is my code right now and what it does is when i click on the submenu it opens and closes.

```
// Dropdown menu
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function () {
    $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");

    } else {

        $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
        $(this).next(".sidebar-submenu").slideDown(200);
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");


    }

});
```

And what i want to do is basicly this: http://jsfiddle.net/7qyE9/3/

I cant replicate that example with the code that i am using right now...

Comment: Why can't you replicate that example in your code?

Comment: Can you share your html code

Comment: This has been covered many times. Instead of all that logic, just close everything and open the current submenu. Show your HTML for more help.

Comment: You are using `$(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");` in both the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: @AkhilAravind i added my html code on original post.

Answer (score 1):

**Important:**  We rather help to find solutions than serve them. I remember asking the first questions myself. That's why I'll help you this time. Create a code snippet with your code so we can help you get what you want in the future. If you will not be able to find what you did wrong, give as a better example of your work.

---

This is a combination of both codes you posted. Should work as desired. Note that you need to have `active` classes if you want them to be opened at the beginning.

```js
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function () {
    $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);

    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");

  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");

    } else {
        $(this).next(".sidebar-submenu").slideDown(200);
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <div class="sidebar-dropdown active">
         <a>First submenu</a>
         <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
             <li>Item1</li>
             <li>Item2</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     
     <div class="sidebar-dropdown active">
         <a>Second submenu</a>
         <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
             <li>Item3</li>
             <li>Item4</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```